# Returning a status code early for a time consuming function in Flask

Tags: python, web, flask

I have an API route that calls a function (ie: doSomethingForALongTime) that takes some time to finish. If we assume that the function doesn't return anything to the client, is there a work around to just call the function and send the status code 200 while the function is doing it's job?

```
@application.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
def api_route():
    doSomethingForALongTime() 
    return 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with some caveats. The usual way to handle this is to use a 'task queue', such as
[celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) or
[rq](http://python-rq.org/)
(there's a walk-through of how to use `rq` in chapter 22 of the
[flask mega tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)). The approaches require that, at least, you have `redis` running, and are running separate worker processes.

The idea is hand a task off to the task queue in your handler (route), then return a response to the browser while a worker in a separate process picks the task up from the queue and runs it.

It's also possible to run a 'worker thread' in your app, and have the handler queue up work for it. I have a proof-of-concept for that [here](https://github.com/davewsmith/play/tree/master/flask-worker-thread), with the caveat that I've only used it for personal apps. The caveat is that this is only really suitable for a personal webapp.